# Python regex String array to float array

Tags: python, regex

I am a beginner to python regexes. I achieved what I needed but it is really ugly as I am missing experience. My goal is to convert an array of strings of the form:

```
notes = ["10.0% higher", "5.0% lower", "Same as", "21.2% lower"]
```

to an array of floats, so that the above array yields:

```
changes = [10.0,-5.0,0,-21.2]
```

The code below achieves that but is really repetitive and bad style. How can I optimize that?

```
changes = []
for note in notes:
    m = re.search(r"(?:(\d+\.\d+\%\shigher)|(\d+\.\d+\%\slower)|(Same\sas))", note)
    if m:
        if m.groups(0):
            if m.groups(0)[0]:
                changes += [float(re.match(r"(\d+\.\d+)", m.groups(0)[0]).groups(0)[0])]
            elif m.groups(0)[1]:
                changes += [-float(re.match(r"(\d+\.\d+)", m.groups(0)[1]).groups(0)[0])]
            else:
                changes += [0.0]
print changes
```

Comment: You should really post this on CodeReview.SE... Also, you could change these 2 if statements, `if m: if m.groups(0):`, onto one, `if m and m.groups(0):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `findall` you can do this in a single regex:

```
notes = ["10.0% higher", "5.0% lower", "Same as", "21.2% lower"]

changes = []
for note in notes:
    m = re.findall("(?:(\d+\.\d+)% )?(higher|lower|Same as)", note)
    if len(m):
       if m[0][1] == 'higher':
          changes += [float(m[0][0])]
       elif m[0][1] == 'lower':
          changes += [-float(m[0][0])]
       else:
          changes += [0.0]

print changes
```

Comment: this is the most comprehensible solution for me

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def get_val(s):
    if "higher" in s:
        return float(re.sub("\D", "", s))
    if "lower" in s:
        return -float(re.sub("\D", "", s))
    return 0

notes = ["10.0% higher", "5.0% lower", "Same as", "21.2% lower"]    
changes = [get_val(s) for s in notes]
print(changes)
```

prints

```
[100.0, -50.0, 0, -212.0]
```

---

A lot faster than regex (relevant for large inputs, for smallish inputs not so much) would be `string.translate`:

```
import string

all_chars = string.maketrans('', '')
no_digits = all_chars.translate(all_chars, string.digits)

def get_val(s):
    if "higher" in s:
        return float(s.translate(all_chars, no_digits))
    if "lower" in s:
        return -float(s.translate(all_chars, no_digits))
    return 0

notes = ["10.0% higher", "5.0% lower", "Same as", "21.2% lower"]
changes = [get_val(s) for s in notes]
print(changes)
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can put pattern to variable and visually split groups
- You can match float strings in pattern and convert them directly
- You can use `or` to select matched group

Example:

```
import re


notes = ["10.0% higher", "5.0% lower", "Same as", "21.2% lower"]

pattern = '(?:' \
    '((\d+\.\d+)\%\shigher)|' \
    '((\d+\.\d+)\%\slower)|' \
    '(Same\sas)' \
')'

changes = []

for note in notes:
    gr = re.search(pattern, note).groups()
    num = float(gr[1] or gr[3] or 0) * (-1 if gr[3] else 1)
    changes.append(num)

print(changes)  # [10.0, -5.0, 0.0, -21.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#! python3

notes = ["10.0% higher", "5.0% lower", "Same as", "21.2% lower"]

def adjustments(notes):
    for n in notes:
        direction = -1.0 if n.endswith('lower') else 1.0
        offset = 0.0 if n.lower() == 'same as' else float(n.split('%')[0])
        yield offset * direction

changes = [x for x in adjustments(notes)]
print(changes)
```